# UDP client / server adress is not valid in local network

Tags: python, sockets, udp, lan

I have been dealing with client / server chat over UDP for local network as you can see in this topic [Using one socket in UDP chat using threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40305424/using-one-socket-in-udp-chat-using-threading). The working code is marked as answer to my question and I am using it now to build my app as I want it.

I have created two different files which differ only in `host` and `port` values, because I need this chat to work in my local network - between two computers. I have set those two PCs with IP adress #1 `192.168.0.1` and the second is `192.168.0.2`.

Here is the main function which I have right now:

## Computer 1 (ip: .0.1)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    rec = Receiving('', 8000)
    send = Sending('username', "192.168.0.2" , 8888, 8888)
    rec.run()
    send.run()
```

## Computer 2 (ip: .0.2)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    rec = Receiving('', 8888)
    send = Sending('username2', '192.168.0.1' , 8000, 8000)
    rec.run()
    send.run()
```

My firewall is off, I can ping each IP adress from both computers with no problem. I get error every time when I try to send a message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\workspace\Chat\server.py", line 61, in <module>
    send = Sending('...', '192.168.0.1' , 8888, 8888)
  File "C:\Users\febeks\workspace\Chat\server.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.sock = self.create_socket()
  File "C:\Users\...\workspace\Chat\server.py", line 19, in create_socket
    sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

I have also found out, that if I set the IP address of computer #1 its own IP address in `Sending`, then it won't give me error, but it is wrong because I want to set the IP in `Sending` to the target computer, which I want to chat with. It doesn't make sense to me at all.

I have tried to search the internet for answer, but none of the answers solved my problem.

Regarding to comments, I put full code except `main` ,which is different for each computer, into this topic so it is more clear and all together.

```
class Sending():
    def __init__(self, name, tHost, tPort, target):
        self.name = name
        self.host = tHost
        self.port = tPort
        self.target_port = target
        self.sock = self.create_socket()

    def create_socket(self):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
        return sock

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def send_loop(self):
        name = input('Name:')
        while True:
            message = input('Enter message: ')
            data = bytearray()
            data.extend(name.encode('utf-8') + message.encode('utf-8'))
            self.sock.sendto(bytearray(data), (self.host, self.target_port))

    def run(self):
        th2 = threading.Thread(name='send', target=self.send_loop)
        th2.start()

class Receiving():
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

    def create_socket(self):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
        while True:
            data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1500)
            print('\nReceived: ' + data.decode('utf-8') + str((addr)))

    def run(self):
        th1 = threading.Thread(name='rec', target=self.create_socket)
        th1.setDaemon(True)
        th1.start()
        return
```

Comment: show full error message in question. Which line makes problem ? Maybe you have to set address instead of empty string.

Comment: You need to actually post all the code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: The code in that other question doesn't look right to me. `sock.bind((self.host, self.port))` is wrong, it's trying to bind the local address of the socket to the address of the other machine.

Comment: @Barmar what do you suggest to change? It is still a bit confusing to me.

Comment: I don't think you need to use `sock.bind()` in `Sending`.

Comment: @Barmar it works now! But I have one question, I am sending to port 8001 from PC1 and to port 8000 from PC2 and when I receive message, it shows me different ports, like 59424 and 56257.... Why that? How can it change the ports?

Comment: The local port that you send from is an ephemeral port, not the same one that you're listening for responses on.

Comment: Thank you very much! All clear!